# Jquery xml webservice parsing error

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, asmx

I am trying to display asmx webservice data to a div with jquery. I am unable to get it work and it gives a parse error with the below code.
 [Here is my fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/zbscrc3a/)

Webservice:    http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote",
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: "4",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('StockQuotes').each(function () {
                        var title = $(this).find('Symbol').text();
                        var created = $(this).find('Date').text();

                        alert(title);
                    });
                },
                error: function (msg, m2, m3) {
                    alert(m2);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You arn't actually getting the webservice data so its not even trying to parse it based on that fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

The web service is expecting a `symbol` parameter. But in your code, I didn't find any XML query `data` that is being sent.

Check the proper format of request/responses [here](http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote)

Comment: Even after adding data as "4". I am getting same error.

Comment: how did you add "4"? you need to create proper XML structure to query the service, otherwise you'll get exception.

Comment: The syntax of the data needs to be symbol="ABC" or symbol=STRINGOFSTOCK